# Does Excel-DNA support thread-safe RTD wrapper functions?

Tags: c#, .net, excel, multithreading, excel-dna

This article is talking in the last paragraph of improvements in thread safe RTD Excel functionality in 2020:

https://github.com/Excel-DNA/Tutorials/tree/master/SpecialTopics/RTD

It concludes: "This will allow future versions of Excel-DNA to support thread-safe RTD wrapper functions"

Does the latest Excel Dna support thread safe RTD wrapper functions ? If not is there an ETA on it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We've not implemented the thread-safe RTD wrapper support yet. It is bubbling towards the top of the list, but I can't give a useful time frame. Signing up as a [GitHub Sponsor](https://github.com/sponsors/Excel-DNA/) to the project is the best way to encourage ongoing development.